# symbols inserted in different font

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a userform with buttons for inserting symbols into my document.

The button command has the below code:

```
  Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=83, Font:="Symbol"
```

However, after insertion the font of the symbol remains the original font in the document.

e.g. My document is in `Times New Roman`, and the above code adds the symbol in `Times New Roman`. How does this happen when the code specifies otherwise?

p.s. I am trying to achieve the opposite of this behavior:
A document contains some symbols in 'Symbol' font, and I want them in the document's default font(`Times New Roman`).

Comment: This isn't making any sense. The code you give us retains the original font and in "p.s." you say you want to retain the original font. So what's the problem? Give us exact steps to reproduce what you're asking about.

Comment: yes, the code retains the original font; however, I have a document where the symbols are in Symbol font. When I try to replace those using the code, the font remains 'Symbol'